# How to make borders with images

Tags: html, css, image

I have 6 images that makes a box. (for the borders, and corners), How would I put the images together and make it dynamic and get bigger  when I put more content in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a [sliding doors approach](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) (also see the [follow up article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/)) generalised to [four way expansion](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/), or put all your images back into one and investigate the [`border-image` property](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/).

If you want to support IE and older browsers then sliding doors is the way to go, if you're targeting smartphones then `border-image` will probably be OK.

Comment: Can you explain the border-image? Do I have to put all of the images together one image and just use that one single image?

Comment: @Kawohi Yes, read the tutorial I linked to, it does a better job of explaining it than I could manage in a comment.